# Start to teleop My own Robot Model

Tags: ros, gazebo, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I built my own robot model as a urdf file .. Like In this [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Movable%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF)

It looks In RVIZ :
[image: image description]

Now, I want to start to test apps on my model like teleop to start to move it with Keyboard .

What Should I do ??
I think firstly Open a world to Gazebo
Secondly, Load my robot on the world .... I DON'T Know HOW ???????????
Third, Start to operate teleop node to start to move .... I WANT a CODE fit to my robot model ??
Actually I can't find a Stack that can operate apps on my robot

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146396/start-to-teleop-my-own-robot-model/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27095/raissi/) on 2016-06-07**:
hello salma , i am now working on same you project , really i found the problems in the control for move it . i want your help if you have a time for give me some indications ! thank you . my gmail :    raissimohamedimam@gmail.com for contact me . i am in wait your help by all passion ! thank you

**Comment by [Zahraa23](https://answers.ros.org/users/154433/zahraa23/) on 2023-06-17**:
Hello there,
I want to ask you if the teleop package of turtlebot worked with your project as I am facing the same problem now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need gazebo to simluate your robot. This is not trivial and might need some work. However, I think the gazebo tutorials are actually quite good. There is a lot of documentation. I would start with the general gazebo tutorials and then once you understand how it works, check out the tutorials which are specific to gazebo+ROS http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2014-04-04**:
Hi demmeln, I have finished my robot description files About environment world in gazebo, Not a problem I will use the default gazebo world file The issue now that i want to use the teleop app like that in the turtlebot SDK or whatever on my own robot But i didn't find any apps on a similar robot based on wild thumper base on ROS

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2014-04-09**:
Salma if your version of ROS is Hydro you need to install gazebo 1.9, this version is the compatilbe with hydro.
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-09**:
@salma: Did you go through all the gazebo tutorials?

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2014-04-10**:
In my case I did all gazebo tutorials of gazebo version 1.9.
The important ones are: 1.Building a Robot With SDF, explain how to build your robot and add a sensor to your robot too;  2.Making a World, you need to create a world to run in gazebo and do spwan of your robot; 3. ROS Integration, explain how to do a roslaunch to run your world and do spwan of your robot.
My advise is, if you don't understand what they are saying, install the package of turtlebot and see how it works. http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot
Ahhh another advise, use xacro to build your robot not sdf because, xacro you can find more support info.
In this moment I am working with turtlebot, and I can run him in gazebo without any problems.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2014-04-12**:
Hi Raul, demmeln
I have finished my robot model description and a world on gazebo . I have tried turtlrbot teleop package and it works well now on Gazebo :).
Now i want to build a map by gmapping .
I have opened Rviz but some error occur in RobotModel plugins and laser scan plugins.
i am working to fix them.
thanks all for your help.

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2014-04-14**:
Hi Salma, do you have a error on Global Status Error too? if yes, may be you have Global Options  "Fixed frame: map" you need to put here a link of your robot, in turtlebot that is my case is "base_link". This will fix the Global Status and RbotoModel. The LaserScan is too the topic problem I think, in normal cases the topic that public data of laser is "/scan", search using this "rostopic list" or "rqt_graph", and find which topic is publishing, use too "rostopic echo /nametopic" to see the values.
I hope this helps.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2014-04-15**:
Hi Raul, Yes this helps me thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably not the correct answer as I'm confused myself.  I believe you need to create a world file that contains your robot (including joints and collision definitions) and open that world file in Gazebo.  At that point you can use the force menu in Gazebo to manually apply forces to the robot joints and move your robot around the simulated world.  What it takes to get your own robot control code running and connected to the simulated robot joints, I do not know.  The Gazebo tutorials seem disjointed to me.  I wish they would take a newbie from an empty world all the way through creation of a robot model and then creation of robot control software and then execution of that robot control software within the Gazebo simulation.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2014-04-04**:
Hi Kurt,
I have finished my robot description files
About environment world in gazebo, Not a problem I will use the default gazebo world file
The issue now that i want to use the teleop app like that in the turtlebot SDK or whatever on my own robot
But i didn't find any apps on a similar robot based on wild thumper base on ROS